# If $L/K$ is a field extension, is $\text{Aut}(K)$ a normal subgroup of $\text{Aut}(L)$?

Tags: automorphism-group

If $L/K$ is a field extension, is $\text{Aut}(K)$ a normal subgroup of $\text{Aut}(L)$ (possibly under some extra conditions on $L$ and $K$) and if so what is the quotient isomorphic to, possibly $\text{Aut}(L/K)$, if this is at all correct?

Note: This is when thinking functions in $\text{Aut}(K)$ map $L\setminus K$ with the identity.

Comment: A map which fixes $L \setminus K$ but not $K$ is not a field automorphism if $L \neq K$.

Comment: Is there a natural way to embed $\text{Aut}(K)$ in $\text{Aut}(L)$ then?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, in other words, can every automorphism of $K$ be extended to an automorphism of  $L$?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Why?

Comment: Suppose $\sigma \in \textrm{Aut}(L)$ fixes $L \setminus K$ and suppose  $a \in L \setminus K$ and $b \in K$ such that $\sigma(b) \neq b$. Then $\sigma(a + b) = \sigma(a) + \sigma(b) = a + \sigma(b) \neq a + b$, but this is a contradiction because $a + b \in L \setminus K$.

Comment: @lhf yes, that's what I'm wondering. Is there a natural way to extend an automorphism to an extension field?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, not in general. See the comment by R. van Dobben de Bruyn at https://mathoverflow.net/q/265400.

Comment: Isn't this much more general than field automorphism groups?